# python float to in int conversion

Tags: python, floating-point

I have an issue that really drives me mad. Normally doing `int(20.0)` would result in `20`. So far so good. But:

```
levels = [int(gex_dict[i]) for i in sorted(gex_dict.keys())]
```

while `gex_dict[i]` returns a float, e.g. `20.0`, results in:

```
"invalid literal for int() with base 10: '20.0'"
```

I am just one step away from munching the last piece of my keyboard.

Comment: Can you post the type of content you have in `gex_dict`. I think you have strings which look like floats instead of floats.

Comment: Hi Jamylak, yes you are right, those were strings instead of floats, thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`'20.0'` is a string, not a `float`; you can tell by the single-quotes in the error message. You can get an `int` out of it by first parsing it with `float`, then truncating it with `int`:

```
>>> int(float('20.0'))
20
```

(Though maybe you'd want to store floats instead of strings in your dictionary, since that is what you seem to be expecting.)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the value is a string, not a float.  So you need `int(float(gex_dict[i]))`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the problem is that `gex_dict[i]` actually returns a string representation of a float `'20.0'`. Although int() has the capability to cast from a float to an int, and a string representation of an integer to an int. It does not have the capability to cast from a string representation of a float to an int.

The documentation for int can be found here:
http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#int

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have a string and not a float, see this as comparison:

```
>>> int(20.0)
20
>>> int('20.0')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '20.0'
```

You can workaround this problem by first converting to float and then to int:

```
>>> int(float('20.0'))
20
```

So it would be in your case:

```
levels = [int(float(gex_dict[i])) for i in sorted(gex_dict.keys())]
```